# Login system for Jobseekers and employers multiple inner joins?

Tags: mysql, database, authentication

Creating a login system where the user selects between whether they want to sign up as a jobseeker or a employer.
 I have a `USERS` table which contains foreign keys to both Jobseekers ( J_id ) and employers ( J_id ) tables. Which reads as follows:

```
  create table `origincareer_zymichost_db`.`USERS`( 
   `U_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
   `password` CHAR(22) NOT NULL,
   `jobCategory` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   J_Id int,
   E_Id int,
   PRIMARY KEY ( U_id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( J_id ) REFERENCES Jobseekers( J_id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( E_id ) REFERENCES Employers( E_id )
);
```

`SQL INNER JOIN` Syntax is this correct? how to do 2 inner joins? :

```
SELECT USERS.username, Jobseekers.J_id
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN Jobseekers
ON USERS.U_id=Jobseekers.U_id
ORDER BY USERS.username;
```

thank you

Comment: You should also share the create table statement of tables USERS and Jobseekers .. What question(s) do you have for your database can you explain that in simple plain english? Please update your question with this information!

Comment: Just a start...  I would just have a login ID... one person could be both a job seeker AND an person working for an employer who some day may want to look for jobs too.

Comment: But a jobseeker wants to be employed be a employer you see, but thank you for the feedback.